# Pivot column to a row based on values in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have this table of two attributes (see picture). Now I have been trying to use PIVOT to accomplish my task but without success.

I want to have:

- All `WorkOperationID` on one row for `SparePartListID=1`
- All `WorkOperationsID` that corresponds to `SparePartsListID=2` on row 2.

Is this possible to achieve?

[image]

Comment: There are more SparePartsList = 2 than SparePartsList = 1

Comment: add example of your desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help or Row_Number() and some dynmic SQL.  This is assuming you want **DENSE** columns, otherwise remove the **`Partition By SparePartsListID`**   (both of them)

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName(RN) From (Select Distinct RN=Row_Number() over (Partition By SparePartsListID Order by WorkOperationID) From YourTable) A Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
Select  @SQL = '
Select [SparePartsListID],' + @SQL + '
From (
        Select *
              ,RN=Row_Number() over (Partition By SparePartsListID Order by WorkOperationID) 
         From  YourTable
     ) A
 Pivot (max(WorkOperationID) For [RN] in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

Returns

```
SparePartsListID    1       2       3       4       ...
1                   101282  101344  101398  NULL    ...
2                   84108   84921   85528   86228   ...
```

> **EDIT - If you Don't want DYNAMIC extend [1],[2],[3],[4],...,[n]**

```
Select *
From (
        Select *
              ,RN=Row_Number() over (Partition By SparePartsListID Order by WorkOperationID) 
         From  YourTable
     ) A
 Pivot (max(WorkOperationID) For [RN] in ([1],[2],[3],[4]) ) p
```